# Sinon mock Promise.all in NodeJS controller

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Using Promise.all within NodeJS controller. Unable to mock this in Sinon.

A controller calls a reusable method to grab specific data. However, in one case I want to append additional data to each of the results in the array. Using Promise.all to do this. However, despite researching the questions here, I have not found a solution to mock Promise.all in this instance. Looked at `setTimeout/done` around the `expect`. Not sure where `done` needs to be called here to make it work.

Controller

```
getItems()
...

let items = await Method.findAllByQuery(query);
if (userId && items) {
   items = await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
      let tmpItem = item;
      tmpItem.count = await AnotherMethod.countDocuments(query).exec();
      return tmpItem;
   }));
}
results.items = items;
```

Sinon Test

```
let stubMethod = sinon.stub(Method, 'findAllByQuery');
it('Should return a 200 if userId passed', async () => {
   req.userId = '123456789';
   stubMethod.returns(items);
   await ShowController.getItems(req, res);
   expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});
```

The result should be `200`. Instead, there is a timeout

`Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Comment: The `Method.findAllByQuery` is asynchronous, try to stub it with `stubMethod.resolves(items)`. Also, just curious, why do you need `Promise.all`? You don't do anything asynchronous inside it.

Comment: There is an async method inside the promise. I'm just not showing all the code here since i don't know how sensitive things are :)

Comment: `stubMethod.resolves(items)` does not fix the issue

Comment: What about `AnotherMethod`, have you tried stubbing it?

Comment: yes! that gets me passed the timeout issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stub `Promise.all`. You have to stub all asynchronous methods in your function: `Method.findAllByQuery(query)` and `AnotherMethod.countDocuments(query).exec()`:

```
let stubMethod = sinon.stub(Method, 'findAllByQuery');
let stubExec = sinon.stub();
let stubCountDocuments = sinon.stub(AnotherMethod, 'countDocuments');
stubCountDocuments.returns(stubExec);
it('Should return a 200 if userId passed', async () => {
    req.userId = '123456789';
    stubMethod.resolves(items);
    stubExec.resolves(1);
    await ShowController.getItems(req, res);
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});
```

Comment: `items` is whatever your stub function should return. In example above, if I do `stubMethod.resolves([])` then `findAllByQuery` returns `[]`.

Comment: I understand that but `items` is not defined in your example and as is, your test will fail.

Comment: My answer explained what methods to stub. In the context of question it doesn't matter what exactly that method returns. I've just copied that line from the original question. It can be `const items = []; stubMethod.resolves(items);`